# c# Local Database insert into doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I tried too many times but insertion doesn't work!
Please help me..

codes:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mytbl(Id, Nav) VALUES('yek','du')", conn); //yek and du are examples
//Following command doesn't work, too
//"INSERT INTO mytbl(Id, Nav) VALUES('"+tb.Text+"','"+tb2.Text+"')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors ?

Comment: there is not any error. Program execute normally but when i check the table, i don't see any new items..

Comment: How do you know.  You are not even checking for result or error code.

Comment: edit: after I stop the program, I look at the database. So I check it. While execution there is not error. How can I check errors?

Comment: Look up the documentation.  I haven't used sqlcommand.  So, are you expecting me to look it up, because you can not be bothered to ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.  Describe the behavior that you observe, including how you observe it, and also describe the behavior you expect.

Comment: "I look at the database" In all likelihood you are looking at the wrong database. Are you certain you're looking at the one defined in your connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `VictoryDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VictoryDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working but the db(.mdf) is getting copied to **\bin\debug** directory first and the app is using that one(\bin\debug\Database1.mdf). Use the following code to get the db (.mdf) path which is present at your App root directory.

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToLower().Replace("\\bin", "").Replace("\\debug", "").Replace("\\release", "").TrimEnd('\\');

string conStr =  "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + path + "\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```